# Upgrading openssl from 0.9.8 to 1.0.2 / Ubuntu 8.04 LTS

Tags: apache, ubuntu, openssl

first of all, thanks for your time trying to help.

I have an old server, `Ubuntu 8.04`, not supported anymore. 
Since June, a payment platform I'm working with has deactivated the TLSv1 and SSL.

My server is running under :

```
Apache 2.2.8 /
Openssl 0.9.8 /
PHP 5.2.17 /
Ubuntu 8.04
```

I have installed a new version of openssl (using wget) :

```
openssl version 
OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018
```

My version of apache is too old to support TLSv1.2, I need to upgrade it to apache 2.2.23 minimum version.

How to compile apache in order to take into account the new OpenSSL version?

PS: I just take a new server to migrate my website, but it takes time to adapt the code... Changing the server is not an option for now .. I need to make it work as fast as possible, and then I'll be able to focus on the error introduced by PHP 7...

Thanks in advance to help the newbie i am..

Comment: I just thought 8.04 as typo... Can the old release help you? http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/

Comment: hello. no didn't help.. i replaced the sourcelist with this url, but didn't solve my issue ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this old Ubuntu is no longer supported, you can most probably not use the repos to install Apache.

Compiling your own is doable following instructions here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/install.html.

When you run `./configure` you will have to use `--enable-ssl` and `--with-ssl=DIR`. The DIR is where OpenSSL resides (not the source code, but the installation directory).  Check the `./configure` output to identify any missing requisites.

Once you run `make install`, you will then have to compile PHP with that new OpenSSL, and link to the newly compiled Apache.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php

---

This is how I compile my HTTP (notes taken a while back, some versions might differ).  Adapt for your needs, and this is provided "as is", no warranty :-)
The prerequisites are based on RHEL 6 or 7, adapt as required.

```
Required software:
- apr-1.6.2
- apr-iconv-1.2.1
- apr-util-1.5.4
- httpd-2.4.26
  (identical  procedure used with previous versions of 2.4)
- openssl-1.0.2l 
  (identical prodecure used with older versions of 1.0)
- Unzip and untar these under /opt/app/SOURCES

System setup

Ask Unix to create:
- /opt/app/httpd, owner httpd, group httpd, permissions 775
-  user httpd, group httpd

Create these directories
- /opt/app/apr
- /opt/app/apr-iconv
- /opt/app/apr-util
- /opt/app/httpd
- /opt/app/openssl
- all owned by httpd, group httpd, permissions 750

Procedure

Get Unix to install prerequisites
for F in libxml2.i686 libxml2.x86_64 libxml2-devel.i686 libxml2-devel.x86_64 apr-devel.i686 apr-devel.x86_64 apr-util.i686 apr-util.x86_64 pcre-devel.i686 pcre-devel.x86_64 autoconf libtool
do
        yum install -y $F
done

Switch to the httpd user.

Install APR
cd /opt/app/SOURCES/apr-1.6.2
./buildconf
./configure --prefix=/opt/app/apr
make
make install 

Keep the directory as is, APR Util and APR Iconv require the APR sources to refer to. 

Install APR Util
cd /opt/app/SOURCES/apr-util-1.5.4
./buildconf --with-apr=/opt/app/SOURCES/apr-1.6.2
./configure --prefix=/opt/app/apr-util --with-apr=/opt/app/apr
make
make install

Install APR Iconv
cd /opt/app/SOURCES/apr-iconv-1.2.1
./configure --prefix=/opt/app/apr-iconv --with-apr=/opt/app/apr
make
make install

Install OpenSSL
cd /opt/app/SOURCES/openssl-1.0.2l
export CFLAGS=-fPIC
./config --prefix=/opt/app/openssl --openssldir=/opt/app/openssl shared
make clean
make
make test
make install 

Install Apache
cd /opt/app/SOURCES/httpd-2.4.26
export  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/app/openssl/lib
./configure --prefix=/opt/app/httpd --with-mpm=worker --enable-rewrite --enable-ssl --with-ssl=/opt/app/openssl --enable-proxy --enable-rewrite --enable-log-forensic --enable-log-debug --enable-expires --enable-headers --enable-unique-id --with-apr=/opt/app/apr --with-apr-util=/opt/app/apr-util
make
make install
vi /opt/app/httpd/bin/envvars
    Add /opt/app/openssl/lib to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH 

Note for the ./configure:  this was done to build an Apache used as a proxy.  change the --enable* options as required.


Configure HTTP
- The original configuration files after installation are saved in /opt/app/httpd/conf/original
- While it is impossible to cover all configuration options, at least these should be changed from the install configuration:
--- Listen 80: change as required.
--- User httpd
--- Group httpd
--- ServerAdmin EMAILADDRESS
--- ServerName <HOSTNAME>:80
--- Comment or uncomment the modules, as required
--- Uncomment slotmem_shm_module
--- Comment: CustomLog "logs/access_log" common
--- Uncomment: CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
--- Comment the following sections (the entire section!):
----- <IfModule alias_module>
----- <IfModule cgid_module>
----- <Directory "/opt/app/httpd/cgi-bin">
--- Uncomment:
----- Include conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf
----- Include conf/extra/httpd-default.conf
----- Edit conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf
----- Change performance options as required.  The defaults are ok until you have a large amount of traffic.
----- Edit conf/extra/httpd-default.conf
----- Comment AccessFileName .htaccess
----- ServerTokens Prod

--- Test the configuration:     /opt/app/httpd/bin/apachectl -t
--- Start it and access it with a browser.  It should return a simple "It works!" message (unless you have installed some HTML content).
```

---

And this is my procedure for PHP compilation, again no warranty, "as is".  You can ignore the parts about DB2, Oracle and PostgreSQL if you do not connect to these DB.

```
Prerequisites
- A compiled version of Apache HTTP and it's requisites.  See HTTP installation.
- It "could" work with RedHat's compiled Apache, but it is not recommended.  If RH's Apache is used, might as well use RH's PHP build.
- PHP source code: download from http://php.net
- This procedure has been tested with success on versions: 5.3.13, 5.5.7, 5.6.3, 5.6.30.  No modifications were required.

Install Red Hat pre-requisites:
- libxml, libxml-devel
- libpng, libpng-devel
- libjpg, libjpg-devel

If using DB2
- Install DB2 client under /opt/app
- PHP searches for the lib directory, so:
       cd /opt/app/ibm/db2/V10.5
       ln -s lib64 lib

If using Oracle
- Install the Oracle Instant Client in /opt/app/oracle

Overview
PHP must be compiled and "linked" to Apache.  Apache must therefore be compiled before PHP.
Depending on which database PHP will connect to, the configure options must be changed.
http://php.net has more documentation and details for the build process, this is just what was used.

Build

Pre-compile configure

The configure command will detect what other software is installed on the system and link libraries.
Note for the database clients: they can all be linked at the same time, but it is recommended to link only the ones required.

The command is:
       ./configure --with-apxs2=/opt/app/httpd/bin/apxs \
                   --prefix=/opt/app/php \
                   --with-config-file-path=/opt/app/php \
                   --enable-zip \
                   --with-zlib \
                   --enable-mbstring \
                   --with-gd \
                   --with-pear \
                   --with-pdo-odbc=ibm-db2,/opt/app/ibm/db2/V10.5 \              # if using DB2 only!
                   --with-oci8=instantclient,/opt/app/oracle/instantclient_11_2  # if using Oracle only!
                   --with-pgsql \                                                # if using PostgreSQL only!
                   --with-pdo-pgsql                                              # if using PostgreSQL with PDO only!
 

Compile
     make clean
     make
     make test
     make install 
 

$(make test) will report errors for the Oracle driver. MANY errors! The driver will still work (it was used for the nettracker replacement scripts to load Pharmaclik IBM HTTP Server logs into Oracle). But it will be impossible to use bind variables on Integers. That explains why that script does not use oci_bind* functions.

 

Post-compile configure
     libtool --finish /opt/app/php/lib

     cp php.ini-development /opt/app/php/php.ini
OR
     cp php.ini-production /opt/app/php/php.ini 

In php.ini, add these:
          include_path = ".:/php/includes:/opt/app/php/lib/php"
          date.timezone = 'America/Montreal'
 
Configure Apache

These lines are possibly already there since the PHP $(make install) takes care of it, if the httpd.conf file is "clean" (i.e. has not been modified from the originally installed file).
Add these to httpd.conf:
          LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
          AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me Nic. Should I remove actual apache (installed with the distribution) ? Morevoer, will the command a1ensite work using the new compiled apache. How do I know  all the module installed with php in order to compile the PHP with the same modules ?

Comment: If you recompile Apache, I strongly suggest you to use `--prefix=APACHEDIR` in your `./configure`.  This will define the top directory for your installation.  Most distribution Apache are distributed throughout the operating system, might has well install somewhere else (in fact I never use the distro Apache and put it in /opt/httpd for ex.).  No need to remove it.  For PHP, can your environment still run?  You would display the result of `<?php phpinfo(); ?> which will tell you ALL you need for PHP.

Comment: For `a1ensite`, I searched for it since I do not know what it is and the results are quite few and confusing.  Sorry can't help for that.